# Combining arrays created via multiple threads

Tags: c#, arrays, multithreading, list

I have been trying to create couple of 2-D arrays via multi-threading.  Each threading will generate a small 2-D array.  All of the 2-D will be consolidated and that is where I am having issue.  I commented `"//!this is causing error"` towards the bottom of `SimulatingMethod` method.  Please share your insight.  Thank you.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Threading;

namespace ThreadExample
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            double[,] randSims;
            randSims = SimulatingClass.SimulatingMethod();
        }
    }

    class SimulatingClass
    {
        public static double[,] SimulatingMethod() 
        {
            int rowCount = 9;
            int columnCount = 1;

            int NumberOfCores = System.Environment.ProcessorCount;
            int RowsForEachThread = rowCount / NumberOfCores;

            Thread[] arrayOfThread = new Thread[NumberOfCores];
            DataStuff[] dataStuff= new DataStuff[NumberOfCores];
            for (int i = 0; i < NumberOfCores; i++)
            {

                dataStuff[i] = new DataStuff(RowsForEachThread, columnCount);
                arrayOfThread[i] = new Thread(new ThreadStart(dataStuff[i].UpdateMatrixData));
                arrayOfThread[i].Name = "Thread" + i;
                arrayOfThread[i].Start();
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < NumberOfCores; i++)
            {
                arrayOfThread[i].Join();
            }

            //start combining arrays from different threads
            var list = new List<double[,]>();
            for (int m = 0; m < NumberOfCores; m++)
            {
                list.AddRange(dataStuff[m]); //!this is causing error
            }

            //trying to convert list back to array
            double[,] array3 = list.ToArray();  //!this is causing error

            return array3;

        }

    }

    class DataStuff
    {
        public double G;
        public double[,] M;
        public long steps, trials;

        public DataStuff(long _steps, long _trials)
        {
            M = new Double[_steps, _trials]; // <- M is created in the constructor
            G = 60;
            steps = _steps;
            trials = _trials;
        }

        public void UpdateMatrixData()
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < steps; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < trials; j++)
                {
                    M[i, j] = i + j;
                }
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: What is the kind of error?

Comment: using Task Parallel in .NET4+ would be simpler.

Comment: You want to convert a `List<double[,]>` to a `double[,]`??

Comment: I hope this does not offend you, but you clearly do not have the skills neccessary to do threading directly in .net. There are so many nonos here, such as instanciation of `Thread` as opposed to using the `ThreadPool`, using unsafe memory collections, not implementing Work Stealing, using `System.Environment.ProcessorCount` (which can cause pref issues on HT processors), sleeping the Main Thread and various strong typing errors. Using TPL you could fix half those problems with a tenth of the amount of code.

Comment: Thanks for the comment.  I was trying to meet the homework requirement.  What do you think is the best way to learn to be a better programmer.  Do you have a book or program that you recommend?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should specify the property as follows:

```
list.Add(dataStuff[m].M);
```

It's because the `dataStuff[m]` is of type `DataStuff`, but the type `double[,]` expected as the list item.

---

If I understood you correctly, you need a consolidated 2D array. Try to declare it initially with desired dimensions:

```
double[,] array3 = new double[rowCount, columnCount];
```

And copy data from `dataStuff` array to it after processing:

```
for (int m = 0; m < NumberOfCores; m++)
{
    Array.Copy(dataStuff[m].M, 0, array3, m * columnCount * RowsForEachThread, dataStuff[m].M.Length);
}
return array3;
```

And you don't need `list` at all.

---

Please note, that you have *possible* problems related to the rounding:

```
int RowsForEachThread = rowCount / NumberOfCores;
```

You should handle the situation when the `rowCount` is not divisible by the `NumberOfCores`.

Comment: Yup, I've updated the answer to use the `Add` method instead of the `AddRange`.

Comment: would you please illustrate "And copy data from dataStuff[] to it after processing."